# Does every equation satisfies to be a plane?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

It might not be a typical math question,but i dont know where to ask.

I have some points(x,y,z) that forms building rooftop and tree Geometry. I am trying to distingushing these point. So if a point lies on a plane then it is building rooftop otherwise trees.

To check if a point lies on a plane. I take three nearest neighbour points from the point and create a equation for the plane and insert the point and check if it satisifies the equation.

Now questions are     1) is the method mathematically correct?
2) when i take the three points from trees and create the equation
will the equation also be a plane?

Comment: Three points not on the same line are enough to define a plane. That is why bar stools have 3 legs not 4.

Comment: Answering your Questions (1) The Method is not correct ; We have to make more calculations to check whether a Point is on the roof or on the trees. We require the 4 corners of the roof & have to check (via calculations) whether a Point lies inside the 4 corners or not. (2) When we take 3 Points from the roof or 3 Points from the trees or 3 Points containing both roof & trees , we may still get Planes. That is Part of why the method is not correct. The trees , being in Space , will contain Planes & there may be a Plane common to the roof & the trees. OVERVIEW : we want more Data + Calculations.